# Error running curl and brackets for sequential urls

Tags: url, curl, command-line

I want to download a set of sequential urls using curl in Windows command line.

Here is the command I am running in curl

```
C:\Curl>curl http://xuexiao.eol.cn/html4/1100/1140000[01-99]/index.shtml -o #.html
```

When I run this code, rather than create a sequential url, the bracket is replaced by the beginning of the url, like this:

```
C:\Curl>curl "http://xuexiao.eol.cn/html4/1100/1140000[01-10]/index.shtml" -o #.html

[1/11]: http://xuexiao.eol.cn/html4/1100/114000001http://xuexiao.eo --> #.html
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0

[2/11]: http://xuexiao.eol.cn/html4/1100/114000002http://xuexiao.eo --> #.html
 0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question. There was a problem with version of Curl I had. I was running 7.33, and the problem I described above was known to exist in version 7.33. I upgraded to version 7.45 and the problem was solved.